# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') while testing Login form

Tags: reactjs, testing, automation, jestjs

I am working on creating automation test cases for a website for login component. My requirement is to write all possible test cases like "empty text boxes" should show an error message, "incorrect email/password" should show an error message, "all coerrct details" will go to another page.

```
The below is my test script
```

test('Inputs should be initially empty', async() => {

```
render(<App/>);

const emailInputElement = await screen.findByRole('textbox');
const passwordlInputElement = await screen.findByLabelText("Password");
expect(emailInputElement.value).toBe('');
expect(passwordlInputElement.value).toBe('');
```

});

test('should be able to type an email', async() => {

```
render(<App/>);
const emailInputElement = await screen.findByRole('textbox', {name:/email/i});
fireEvent.change(emailInputElement, {target: {value:'sanjay-alvyl'}});
expect(emailInputElement.value).toBe('sanjay-alvyl');
```

})

test('should be able to type a password', async() => {

```
render(<App/>);
const passwordInputElement = await screen.findByLabelText('Password');
fireEvent.change(passwordInputElement, {target: {value:'Test123'}});
expect(passwordInputElement.value).toBe('Test123');
```

})

test('should show an error message on invalid email', async() => {

```
render(<App/>);
const emailInputElement = await screen.findByRole('textbox', {name:/email/i});
fireEvent.change(emailInputElement, {target: {value:'nhhvgfjf'}});
const submitBtnElement = await screen.findByRole('button',{name:/sign in/i});
fireEvent.click(submitBtnElement);
const emailErrorElement=screen.findByText(/Please fill in this field/i);
console.log(emailErrorElement)
expect(emailErrorElement).toBeInTheDocument();//.toBeInTheDocument();
```

});

```
but the last test case is giving an error while running the test case.
```

```
✓ Inputs should be initially empty (17 ms)
✓ should be able to type an email (17 ms)
✓ should be able to type a password (5 ms)
✕ should show an error message on invalid email (66 ms)
```

● Landing Page › should show an error message on invalid email

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

  24 |     event.preventDefault();
  25 |
> 26 |     let email = event.target.email.value;
     |                                    ^
  27 |     let password = event.target.password.value;
  28 |     authContext.signInWithEmail({ email, password }, (response) => {
  29 |       if (typeof response === "string") {
```

```
Please help ...
```

Comment: You are not awaiting on `findByText` here `const emailErrorElement=screen.findByText(/Please fill in this field/i);`. Maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your test, is seems its your implementation.

Are you sure this code is correct:

```js
  ...
  event.preventDefault();
  let email = event.target.email.value;
  let password = event.target.password.value;
  ...
```

It seems like this is a click button hanlder and the `event.target` (in this case the clicked button) does not contain an email or password property.

And so if `event.target.email is undefined` then you cannot get `value of undefined` - `event.target.email.value`

Your code should look something like this

```
const App = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  handleClick = () => {
    // THIS IS YOUR CLICK HANDLER

    event.preventDefault();
    //we use the state variables
    authContext.signInWithEmail({ email, password }, 
    //...
  }
}
```